# Do iCloud enabled iOS apps require consent from the user?

Tags: ios, icloud

I'm developing an Android app that needs to store the user preferences somewhere in the cloud. If I enable the Google Drive's AppFolder in order to store the user's data, the user needs to give consent by authorizing access to their Google Drive account. I currently don't have my iOS device at hand and can't recall whether I needed to do the same thing when working with iCloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, specific consent for your app is not required before the use of iCloud for documents and data. However, consent can be later be removed from your app in Settings.